# backbone render and postRender function

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am a newbie to Backbone and I met a situation that confused me. In backbone, I found in some views that they have both render and postrender functions, from my understanding, the render function is called to build up the html syntax. But how about postRender, it seems like it is called at the very beginning when I create the view, meaning it is called before render function?

Could anyone please tell me how could I understand this and is there any materials specifying the situation above since I googled but I didn't found an easy understanding answer for a newbie!

Many thanks for this!

Comment: `postRender` isn't part of standard Backbone, so the views that you've found are using it as a custom method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postRender is not a method in Backbone. It is likely a custom method someone has written which will need to be called manually, unless you are extending a Base View which uses this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, it's not part of backbone, but it's a common pattern.

It's a callback that will be called after the view has been rendered. You can use it to provide custom code for dealing with the view's el after it has been rendered.